# Countdown timer between time interval iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nstimer

I need the iPhone to recognize the current time (which I can do fine with NSDate) and have it countdown to the next time interval, say every half hour on the half hour. Example: if the current time is 2:12:30 and the interval is every half hour, I want a countdown to start at 17:30 (17 min 30 seconds left) and go to 0.

Code welcome, but also general program design thoughts welcome too. Here's the code I have for starting a countdown and getting the current time:

```
-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
        if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
            secondsLeft -- ;
            minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
            seconds = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60;
            waitingTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
        }
        else{
            secondsLeft = 10;
        }
    }

    -(void)countdownTimer{
        //secondsLeft = minutes = seconds = 0;
        if([timer isValid])
        {
            [timer release];
        }
       // NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        //[pool release];
    }
    -(NSDate *)getCurrentTime
    {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"mm:ss";

        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
        //[dateFormatter release];
        NSString *currentTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]];
        currentTimeLabel.text = currentTime;
        return now;
    }
```

Comment: I thought about subtracting one time from another with TimeIntervalSinceDate but that requires adding all potential intervals

Comment: To be more specific, I want to just stipulate the desired time interval, every 10 min or every hour, and have it countdown.

Comment: You know the time interval right? then y u using TimeIntervalSinceDate?

Comment: Just put a label use NSTimer to update the label value every second by setting the timer interval to 1.

Comment: If someone hits a button at 2:15:30 and another person using the app hits a button at 2:17:30 I want both timers to countdown to 2:30:00. Updating the countdown isn't the problem, it's making the phone know that if the interval is every 30, only countdown 14:30 and 12:30 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int interval = 30*60; // half hour
long int nowSeconds = (long int) [now timeIntervalSince1970];
int secondsLeft = interval - (nowSeconds % interval); 
NSDate *nextIntervalDate =  [NSDate 
    dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nowSeconds+secondsLeft];

NSLog(@"Now is %@", now);
NSLog(@"The next interval point in time is %@", nextIntervalDate);
NSLog(@"That's another %d seconds (or %02d:%02d)", 
    secondsLeft, secondsLeft/60, secondsLeft%60);
```

Comment: Wow, Mundi that's badass. Thank you!

Comment: I put this in my viewDidLoad method, and each time the viewLoads, it increases the countdown increment by one second. If it loads once, it counts down correctly by one second. Twice, it counts down each second by 2 seconds... Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you have to check if your old `NSTimer` is still running. If it is, cancel it. Otherwise you have 2 or more Timers running, and they all will adjust the countdown fields...

Comment: It was the view will disappear, not the view did unload. Now it works great. Thanks!